# Drush command with Url::fromRoute PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of

Tags: 8, drush

If i create a custom drush command than run a method than exec a loop than 2000 items. For each item i call a Url::fromRoute method:

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('route.custom',
      [ 't' => 'text,
      ['language' => $language])
      ->toString();
```

The drush command finish successfully but i have always this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31457312 bytes) in /var/www/html/sitename/prod/vendor/drush/drush/includes/backend.inc on line 466
```

(this error is caused from Url::fromRoute becouse i had try remove this and don't had a error)

(i can't make a batch, this command is necessary in loop)

Comment: Just run a loop with Url::fromRoute a million times. No memory leak. I printed the urls, how do you process the url strings?

Comment: Everything is done correctly.
But Php returns error at the end (drush command)

Comment: The problem is Url::fromRout don't the process becouse if i comment this part and write url like : $url = '/custom/url'; i dont have any error

Comment: ! Help me, Url:fromRoute is much expansive